# Dataset: Chess Positions and evaluation value

Tags: computer-chess, database, human-versus-machine

Is there anybody out there who knows about a very good dataset of chess **positions** (e.g. FEN notation or 64 fields with pieces in it) combined with a Stockfish-like evaluation score?

I did find something on Kaggle, but the number of games was quite small so it wasn't good for Machine Learning purposes.

Comment: Try asking the Stockfish devs at Fishcooking https://groups.google.com/g/fishcooking. These datasets definitely exist, because they're used for training Stockfish's NNUE.

Comment: @Allure I believe that this should be posted as a answer not a comment this is a perfect answer.

Comment: The answer of Sam Lui has already been amazing, but this one is also good, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://storage.googleapis.com/chesspic/datasets/2021-07-31-lichess-evaluations-37MM.db.gz) is what I use for my training purposes for this [project](https://github.com/samliu21/chess-ai).

[Source](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1smI2B7kiwzkr43TqnCYOpxocZlI0kPUh)

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much! Can you tell what the column between "fen" and "eval" does? It is called "binary" when I open it, but it says its a BLOB datatype and I cannot decode it (maybe I need a different programme)

Comment: Haha honestly, I'm not sure either. I only use the `fen` and `eval` columns.

Comment: Great, I was hoping so, that means I can delete it. THank you :)

Comment: Dang, where did this db come from? I can't find anything like it, trying to decipher how the binary column is storing the info

Comment: Hey, how do I read this .db file?